# Can AMPPS run a virtual host with different ports on the same IP?

Tags: virtual-host, ampps

I want to have two different directories, opened from the same IP, but different ports.  I can't find a way to do this, I have tried many different forums, and Google, but still found nothing.  Can I create a Virtual Host like that?

Example:

```
127.0.0.1:80 -> /Applications/AMPPS/www80

127.0.0.1:12 -> /Applications/AMPPS/www12
```

---

<sup>Yes, I am running on Mac, but the instructions should be the same between Mac and Windows</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible by configuring 2 virtual hosts. You'll need to ensure that Apache is also configured to listen on both ports by modifying `httpd.conf` and adding the following line.
`Listen 12`

You could configure apache similar to the following configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/AMPPS/www80"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:12>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/AMPPS/www12"
</VirtualHost>
```

You would place that configuration in the `sites-available` configuration directory, then use `a2ensite` to actually enable the site and then restart apache.

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/ip-based.html

Comment: probably a dumb question, but where is the `sites-available` configuration directory?

Comment: @Jaketr00 Looks like it may be in `/etc/apache2/extra/` and might be called `httpd-vhosts.conf` - according to this link - https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Comment: I'm still getting an error, "127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data." I tried both `httpd.conf` and `extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: @Jaketr00 Do the apache logs show any attempts or errors when you try and access it?

Comment: both the access logs and error logs show nothing, they are both blank

Comment: Does it work with only one VirtualHost configured?

Comment: the original port, 80, still works no matter what, but the second port, 12, doesnt ever work

Comment: Ah, I had assumed you had configured Apache to listen on port 12 already. You may need to configure that as well - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

Comment: that would have been my issue, i had assumed that the listen worked with commas, so i wrote `Listen 80,12`, thank you